# Logical error in image resizing

Tags: python, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I am using the following code which is responsible for changing the image resolution using the pillow library of python. I am deploying the code on aws lambda. The code runs fine but it has a simple logical flaw while resizing. The code is intended to work as follows :
1. Upload a image to a S3 bucket
2. The code resized the image into 2 different dimensions and upload it to a different bucket.

But the code uploads the 2 images in same dimensions which I am not able to understand why

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def resize_image_DOG(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        dim=(3840,2160)
        image.resize(dim)
        image.save(resized_path)

def resize_image_CAT(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        dim=(1920,1080)
        image.resize(dim)
        image.save(resized_path)


def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path_1 = '/tmp/resized-{}{}'.format('test1',key)
        upload_path_2 = '/tmp/resized-{}{}'.format('test2',key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)

        resize_image_DOG(download_path, upload_path_1)
        resize_image_CAT(download_path, upload_path_2)

        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path_1, '{}resized'.format(bucket), key+'xxxhdpi-3840*2160'+'.png')

        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path_2, '{}resized'.format(bucket), key+'xxxhdpi-1920*1080'+'.png')
```

The 2 resized images which is uploaded to the resized bucket are of same dimension , i.e the first resize_image_DOG dimention (3340x2160) Only, but the name is correct , please help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the pillow documentation: `image.resize()` **returns** a resized image, and doesn't change the passed image.

Therefore, it should be

```
image = image.resize(dim)
```